# NHibernate default child collection and criteria strategies

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

In the domain model, there are a number of entities that have a `Status` enum with values of either `Active` or `Deleted`.

I'm looking for documentation and advice on recommended approaches on how to handle:

1. When fetching a collection of entities that have a `Status` enum, to exclude those with the value set to `Deleted` by default (overridable on a case by case basis)
2. When fetching a child collection of entities, by default to exclude those with the value set to `Deleted` by default.

In summary, I effectively want to keep all data relating to entities with a `Status` enum property, but to exclude those that have a value of `Deleted` for status by default.

Any pointers in the right direction much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a feature in nhibernate called a filter.

Example:

```
  <class name="Post"  table="Posts">
     <id name="Id">
        <generator class="identity"/>
     <id>

    <property name="Title"/>
    <property name="Text"/>
    <property name="PostedAt"/>


    <filter name="NoDeleted" condition="Status <> 'Deleted'"/>
</class>
```

Then when you query:

```
 session.EnableFilter("NoDeleted")
```

For more:
http://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters

Comment: thanks, I was just reading your blog :) Do you know off the top of your head if this applies to child collections by default and how to express this as a global filter in Fluent NHibernate? Do I have to apply the filter to each entity that has a Status property, or can I globally define it for any entity that has a property of the enum type?

Comment: It's ok, I figured it out. If I get a chance, I'll update your answer with the fluent nhibernate version.